# skip_confirmation returning TXID

Tags: python, send-transaction, transaction, solana.py

I'm using a Python library solana-py to send Solana transactions. My question is, if I use `skip_confirmation=False` in `TxOpts` for the opts for the transaction, if the tx fails, will the `send_transaction()` function return the transaction ID (TXID)?

```
opts = TxOpts(skip_confirmation=False)
resp = await solana_client.send_transaction(txn, wallet, opts=opts)
transaction_id = str(resp.value)
```

How will the `resp.value` field look if the transaction fails?

Answer (score 2):

No. If you send a transaction with `skip_confirmation` as `False` and the transaction is not Processed, Confirmed, or Finalized (Depending on your setup) it will raise an error. If you don't want this to happen you can check the transaction status manually.