# What is the fastest way to get a transaction?

Tags: solana-program

What is the fastest way to obtain transaction data while it has not yet been confirmed? In this case, I have a swap transaction that I need to check how much amountOut I received through the swap, but client.get_transaction usually returns something only after the transaction has already been confirmed.. And this can take a while.. I needed a faster way

Comment: You cannot retrieve a transaction that has not been confirmed by the network -- the validator node only stores confirmed transactions in blockstore. https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/34663 has some more information

Answer (score 1):

First things first, while the transaction hasn't been executed, you haven't received any `amountOut`, since prices are constantly changing so the `amountOut` for a swap isn't fixed until you actually execute the transaction. That being said, there's a few things you can do to get a faster response:

- You can add priority fees to your transaction. This will lead to your transaction likely being included in a block sooner and giving you a faster response.
- Using a different RPC provider. The time it takes for an RPC provider to actually index this data can vary, so in some cases this might be the bottle neck as well.
- You could also set slippage to 0 (or close to 0) and through that have (more) predictive output amounts. The downside of this is of course higher rates of transaction failure.
- Finally, you can skip preflight. See how to do this in python here: [skip_confirmation returning TXID](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/4475/skip-confirmation-returning-txid)

Also, I noticed some confusion arises as to why you get the signature instantly but not the transaction. Reason behind this is that the transaction does not need to be executed to find the signature, so if your code is giving you the signature, this does not mean your transaction was necessarily executed or included anywhere.

Comment: I noticed some confusion arises as to why you get the signature instantly but not the transaction. Reason behind this is that the transaction does not need to be executed to find the signature, so if your code is giving you the signature, this does not mean your transaction was necessarily executed or included anywhere.

Comment: I received this error when I try to perform passing processed:

message: "Method does not support commitment below `confirmed`",

Comment: Alright, in this case your best bet is to add priority fees and potentially switch rpc provider. You could also set slippage to 0 (or close to 0) and through that have (more) predictive output amounts. The downside of this is of course higher rates of transaction failure.

Comment: (Edited my answer to include this point and remove my wrong advice of changing the commitment)