# Get transaction details before confirmation

Tags: solana-program

Does anyone know a way to get the details of a swap transaction before confirming it? get_transaction only returns information if the transaction has already been confirmed.

Comment: Could you give a bit more context? Do you have the swap transaction as an object in web3.js?

Comment: I have a swap transaction using python, but client.get_transaction only returns the transaction object after it has been confirmed. I can get the signatures with getSignatureStatuses as soon as I send the transaction, but I needed to know how much I received in this swap as quickly as possible

Comment: Voted to close this as I believe this is the same question as https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8807/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-get-a-transaction/8812#8812 (also by you). I've left an answer there.