# Transactions that disappear

Tags: solana-program

At times, my client creates transactions with send_transaction which, after hundreds of attempts to obtain the status through the getSignatureStatuses method, ends up failing and realizing that the transaction has simply disappeared. Has this ever happened to you? Do you know how I can identify if the transaction disappeared in this case? Or just waiting for a series of attempts?

Here's an example:

```
B7zBUiirDfJ1iE4Ahah1NGSG3WKDgodi6UjHBLwiakZ3BqcimsD6D6kAorQChEmQS6EvF61j6bH9NnNmAxgWK9L
```

Comment: As I answered here https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8807/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-get-a-transaction : The signature doesn't give you a guarantee that the transaction was successfully executed, so you having the signature doesn't necessarily mean your transaction was successful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the fastest way to get a transaction?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8807/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-get-a-transaction)